# Laravel Fav/Unfav functionality, implementing ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

This is my first post, so expect some mistakes,

I've been recently workig on a Blog system using Laravel, and im implementing a like / dislike function for my posts, the thing is, every time you hit the 'like' or fav button the page reloads and then shows the new like.
The thing is i want to make this a real time action, so the page doesn't reloads every time you like or dislike every post. I was thinking of an ajax request, but i have no idea how to implement it. 
Any help here is appreciated.

**Favorite Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Brian2694\Toastr\Facades\Toastr;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FavoriteController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function add($post){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $isFavorite = $user->favorite_posts()->where('post_id',$post)->count();

        if($isFavorite == 0){
            $user->favorite_posts()->attach($post);
            Toastr::success('Has añadido este post a favoritos','success');
            return redirect()->back();
        } else {
            $user->favorite_posts()->detach($post);
            Toastr::success('Has removido este post de favoritos','success');
            return redirect()->back();
        }

    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
        Route::post('favorite/{post}/add','FavoriteController@add')->name('post.favorite');
});
```

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.frontend.app')

@section('title','Home ')


@push('css')
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/frontend/css/home/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ asset('assets/frontend/css/home/responsive.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        .favorite_posts{
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>

@endpush

@section('content')
<div class="main-slider">
    <div class="swiper-container position-static" data-slide-effect="slide" data-autoheight="false"
        data-swiper-speed="500" data-swiper-autoplay="10000" data-swiper-margin="0" data-swiper-slides-per-view="4"
        data-swiper-breakpoints="true" data-swiper-loop="true" >
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <a class="slider-category" href="#">
                    <div class="blog-image"><img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('category/slider/'.$category->image) }}" alt="{{ $category->name }}"></div>

                    <div class="category">
                        <div class="display-table center-text">
                            <div class="display-table-cell">
                                <h3><b>{{ $category->name }}</b></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </a>
            </div><!-- swiper-slide -->
            @endforeach

        </div><!-- swiper-wrapper -->

    </div><!-- swiper-container -->

</div><!-- slider -->

<section class="blog-area section">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="single-post post-style-1">

                        <div class="blog-image"><img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('post/'.$post->image) }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}"></div>

                        <a class="avatar" href="#"><img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('profile/'.$post->user->image) }}" alt="Profile Image"></a>

                        <div class="blog-info">

                            <h4 class="title"><a href="#"><b>{{ $post->title }}</b></a></h4>

                            <ul class="post-footer">
                                <li>
                                    @guest
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="toastr.info('Debes iniciar sesión para añadir a favoritos','info',{
                                            closeButton: true,
                                            progressBar: true,
                                        })"><i class="ion-heart"></i>{{ $post->favorite_to_users->count() }}</a>
                                    @else

                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="document.getElementById('favorite-form-{{ $post->id }}').submit()" class="{{ !Auth::user()->favorite_posts->where('pivot.post_id',$post->id)->count() == 0? 'favorite_posts' : '' }}"><i class="ion-heart"></i>{{ $post->favorite_to_users->count() }}</a>
                                    <form  id="favorite-form-{{ $post->id }}" method="POST" action="{{ route('post.favorite',$post->id) }}" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                    @endguest

                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-chatbubble"></i>6</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-eye"></i>{{ $post->view_count }}</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </div><!-- blog-info -->
                    </div><!-- single-post -->
                </div><!-- card -->
            </div><!-- col-lg-4 col-md-6 -->
            @endforeach

        </div><!-- row -->

        <a class="load-more-btn" href="#"><b>Ver más</b></a>

    </div><!-- container -->
</section><!-- section -->

@endsection

@push('js')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


@endpush
```

**Edit**

Ive wrote some code just to test out

**Blade Form**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="favorito('favorite-form-{{ $post->id }}')" class="{{ !Auth::user()->favorite_posts->where('pivot.post_id',$post->id)->count() == 0? 'favorite_posts' : '' }}"><i class="ion-heart"></i>{{ $post->favorite_to_users->count() }}</a>
                                    <form  id="favorite-form-{{ $post->id }}" method="POST" action="{{ route('post.favorite',$post->id) }}" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
```

**Script**

```
<script>

    function favorito(form){
        var frm = $('#'+form);
        console.log(frm)
        frm.submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Submission was successful.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('An error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Try to make some code and we will be here if you have precise issues

Comment: I've edited my question with some test code, but it doesn't work tho

Comment: Which part doesn't work? What do you see in developer tools? Does it send an ajax request? Does it log anything in the console? Is there anything in the server logs?

Comment: In the `<script>` you're telling it to submit the form and then do the ajax request. Surely you only wanted to do the ajax request?

Comment: You should return string like json or just echo plain string from controller's method instead redirect.